# Camel: route messages based on the contents of a map

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

Currently, my code for routing messages in Camel according to a JMS message header field looks like this:

```
// MyRouteBuilder.java
@Override
public void configure() {

    from(...)
        .choice()
            .when(header("type").isEqualTo("A"))
                .to("proc_a:1")
            .when(header("type").isEqualTo("B"))
                .to("proc_b:1", "proc_b:2", "proc_b:3")
            .when(header("type").isEqualTo("C"))
                .to("proc_c:1", "proc_c:2")
            .when(...)
                .to(...) // ~15 more branches to follow
            .otherwise()
                .to("proc_default");
}
```

Dependend on the value of the `type` header field, there is a specific pipeline of processors that should be used in each case. As you can see, the code is not only repetitive, but also cumbersome to maintain.

There already is a dynamically created `Map<String, String[]>` which maps types to processors, e.g. the key `B` returns `["proc_b:1", "proc_b:2", "proc_b:3"]`. However, I don't know how to make use of it in the scenario shown above.

I also read about the [dynamic router](http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html). However, the given example didn't really help me and I don't want to add more complexitiy by having to manage the state of my routing logic or to ensure thread safety.

I'm grateful for any solution. The only requirements are that I'm stuck with Camel 2.15 and that I'm not allowed to adapt the existing processors (this especially means that the routing logic should not remove any header fields since they are needed later on).

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic to (eg `toD`), where you use some java method to compute the url to route to: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html and here as well about *dynamic to*: http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that I'm stuck with Camel 2.15. According to your link, I think that means I have to go with `.recipientList().method(MessageRouter.class, "routeTo");`. This brings me to two questions. **1.** How can I access the header from inside the `MessageRouter`? **2.** From my understanding, the recipient list pattern distributes the *same* message to multiple destinations. But in my case, each header maps to a list of processors that should be called sequentially (e.g. *proc_b:2* should see the changes made by *proc_b:1*. Is that possible?

Comment: Just return a string with multiple endpoints separated by comma. In fact this is what the recipient list EIP is all about, to send a message to one or more destinations determined by that recipient list.

Comment: I understand that, but as a non-native English speaker, I'm confused by the word *copy* used in the documentation as follows: *"...The second part simply traverses the list and sends a copy of the received message to each recipient"*. But in this case, copy just means a reference to the very same object (so that changes can be observed by all recipients)? Or are we really talking about individual copies?

Comment: In other words, the following property of routes must still be true: *The out message from each step is used as the in message for the next step*. But when each recipient receives a copy of the same message, then I think that's not the same thing.